# Why is my query not showing any results from the collection?

Tags: mongodb, collections

Im currently learning, not doing so great. I am trying to add something to my database and verify its added to my collection but its not showing up when I query it using db.products.find(). The collection is there when I query collections so it means something is in there right?
`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = require('./models/product');

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error")
  console.log(err)
});

async function main() {
  await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test');
};

const p = new Product({
  name: 'Banana',
  price: 1.99,
  category: 'fruit'
});

p.save().then(p => {
  console.log(p)
})
.catch(e => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

`

I ran the file in node, seems to have created the item (this is what i see when i run it).

`

```
{
  name: 'Banana',
  price: 1.99,
  category: 'fruit',
  _id: new ObjectId("636419097d480388c95d9add"),
  __v: 0
}
```

`

I expected it show in the database when I searched for it but it returns nothing, no error, just blank.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.... I never changed the connection name from 'test' to the actual name of my DB. *facepalm